# Syntax error in MySQL check manual

Tags: mysql, sql, terminal

```
 CREATE TABLE info(id KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, email VARCHAR(20), name VARCHAR(20));
```

While using this code, in Ubuntu terminal, i am getting error like below

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, email VARCHAR(20), name
>   VARCHAR(20))' at line 1

pls do help me for this problem. Thanks to replies in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
CREATE TABLE info(
    id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    email VARCHAR(20), 
    name VARCHAR(20),
    primary key(id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
 CREATE TABLE info(id INT NOT null  AUTO_INCREMENT, email VARCHAR(20), name VARCHAR(20),primary key(id));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your "primary key" sintax on MySQL:

`CREATE TABLE info(id not null AUTO_INCREMENT, 
                    email VARCHAR(20), 
                    name VARCHAR(20), 
                    Primary Key(id));`